# Is Board bring up package underlaying architecture dependent?

Tags: linux, embedded

I would like to know Board bring up package underlaying architecture dependent? What actullay wanted to know can we have 64 bit architecture running 32 bit bsp code or BSP code always be 64 bit since BSP code is architecture specific.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely. The BSP is very specific to the architecture of the procesor and the board itself. Having said that, it's possible that there aren't that many changes needed to run at 64-bit. One thing that most BSP's contain is a piece of startup code that initializes the hardware registers in the system. Some of these MAY change when you move to 64-bit.

The second part is the bootloader, which loads the kernel/OS/whatever into RAM (typically - it may just initialize the ROM region to be executable and set it up correctly). Again, this may need changing, as it probably "jumps to the OS in 32 bit", and the OS may expect a 64-bit jump.

Then you have the OS/kernel itself, which clearly needs recompiling.

How much work you actually need to do depends on what architecture the board is, the processor you're using and, most importantly, the requirements from the OS and upper layer software to operate in 64-bit mode - does the memory setup by the init-code or bootloader need to change? When does the switch from 32- to 64-bit happen - inside the OS or outside?

This may not be the answer you were looking for, but I think no one, except those who know the BSP intimately will be able to say exactly what you need to change - I'm pretty sure it's not a complete rewrite, but there may be a load of assumptions along the lines of "we know a pointer is 32 bits, so an int will hold a pointer" or "we know a pointer is four bytes, so we reserve four bytes here..."

Comment: Thanks Mats for your response ,what I understood from your response there could be a case where some part of your BSP code is 32 bit and some part can be 64 bit .Am I right Mats?

Comment: Not quite the words I would use. Something like "If you recompile the right parts to 64-bit, it may well work straight away, but some parts may need changing, and some parts may need to be 32 bit still".

Answer (score 0):

Mats pretty much covered it.  Like any other application it is a combination of the two or multiple platforms you are targeting and the desires and design of the application.  The architectures may be so far apart that it makes no sense at all to try to target them with a single BSP.  If the architectures are similar enough you could target them with a single BSP, but you may or may not choose to.  Linux or the BSDs are a perfect example, there is a fair amount of the code that is multi-platform, with some platform specific parts.  A bsp is no different, often just less complicated, most of your code is generally C or some similar language so it is whatever you compile to that is the target, the bootstrap and some other similar parts are asm and those would be target specific.  FreeRTOS is probably even better of an example than Linux or the BSDs.